# Android How can I create a menu

Tags: android, layout

How can I create a menu in the activity_main.xml? I mean such a menu like for example the Play Store has, where you click on the lines on the top left corner and then the menu opens from the side.

Comment: you must read and learn the basic of android developer in here https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Fragment-Navigation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Novum :** You can use [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) .

The **navigation drawer is a sliding panel** that displays an app’s navigation options on the left side of the screen.  By default this is hidden, but it shows when the user swipes the screen from the left edge or touches the application on the action bar.

You can visit Here for demo
[android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) And [android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example.html)

Navigation drawer widget named **android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```